# Flutter how to get data from the previous screen in which the data is refreshed

Tags: flutter

There is a FirstScreen screen and there is a second SecondScreen called from the first screen, in the first screen a web socket is launched, data arrives on it, on the second screen, let's say there is a Text () widget into which you need to write data from the first screen when SecondScreen is already running. Which way to look?

Comment: you can create a temp variable to hold data , or state. Can you include your snippet that will reproduce the issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this issue using state management like provider or bloc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
var _channel;
var _screenShow = 1;

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstScreen();

  @override
  _FirstScreenState createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  void _serverListen() {
  _channel.stream.listen((message) {

    String res = message.trim();
    if (_screenShow == 1) {
      // update widjet SecondScreen      
    } else if (_screenShow == 2) {
      // update widjet ThirdScreen      
    } else if (_screenShow == 3) {
      // update widjet FourthScreen      
    } else {
      // update widjet FifthScreen      
    }
  },
    onDone: () {
      print('ws channel closed');
    },
    onError: (error) {
      print('ws error $error');
    },
  );
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('ws address'));
  _serverListen();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('first screen'),
    ),
    body: Text('FirstScreen'),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      elevation: 5,
      child: Icon(Icons.grid_on,),
      onPressed: ()  {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}

// SecondScreen

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondScreen();

  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('SecondScreen'),
    ),
    body: Text('update here from first screen'),
  );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use **`Getx Storage`**:

```
dependencies:
  get_storage: ^2.0.3
```

Example:
In 1st Screen You Need to Store the value :

> Initialize storage driver with await:

```
# main() async {   await
 GetStorage.init();   runApp(App()); }
```

use GetStorage through an instance or use directly `GetStorage().read('key')`

```
final box = GetStorage();
```

To read values you use read:

```
print(box.read('quote'));
// out: GetX is the best
```

In the 2nd Page you can remove the key:

To remove a key, you can use remove:

```
box.remove('quote');
```

Comment: Thanks, but probably your option will not work, in the example I indicated to change the widget in the Text (), but in fact I have large arrays and objects

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, implemented using this
https://pub.dev/packages/fbroadcast